# Hibernate transaction annotations in source -- difference between class and method level use?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I am trying to understand what the difference in behavior is when applying the transaction annotation to a class vs. method (and at the property level even?). Does anyone have a solid link for this or perhaps can even capture these differences succinctly for me?

The hundreds of links I've found regarding these annotations only seem to address how to use them in the configuration files rather than in the source. And in the rare case where using them in the source is even mentioned it's very hand wavy.

Here's a concrete example of what I mean by class level:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class MyKickAssClass {
}
```

and the related method level:

```
public class MyOtherKickAssClass {
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void entryPointMethod() {
        //do some work, call other methods of this class, other fun stuff
    }
```

I can make some guesses about what the behavior is in these cases but finding concrete explanations and examples has been a headache.

We're using JBoss.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the JavaDoc:

> The annotation can be specified on the bean class and/or it can be specified on methods of the class that are methods of the business interface or no-interface view.
>
> Specifying the TransactionAttribute annotation on the bean class means that it applies to all applicable business methods of the class. Specifying the annotation on a method applies it to that method only. If the annotation is applied at both the class and the method level, the method value overrides if the two disagree.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html

I also recommend reading the Java EE Tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html

Comment: The behavior described in the first link is what I assumed, I just want more in depth explanation and that second link gives me what I need, thanks.