# @Transactional annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions

is there any difference between:

- add "@Transactional" annotation to whole class
- add for every single method "@Transactional" annotation ?

Using spring and Hibernate ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate transaction annotations in source — difference between class and method level use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4593735/851811)

Comment: It's slightly different (different attribute) but certainly still relevant as it's using the same principles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, if you annotate the class with [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) all methods will be transactional.
If you don't, you can annnotate as [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) only those methods you want to. Additionally, you can specify different attributes for each method, like `isolation`, `propagation`, `timeout`, ...

Also, take a look at this question, this is a possible duplicate of it: [Hibernate transaction annotations in source — difference between class and method level use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4593735/851811)