# How does HibernateTransactionManager work internally

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I have tried looking up for this but every where they just mentioned how to use it but I want to know how does it internally handle when it sees a @Transactional annotation.

Thank you for the response but the other link talks about the difference between annotating the whole class and only one method with @Transactiona. But my questions how does the transaction manager handle it. Does it create to proxies or how exactly does it work internally when ever it sees @Transactional annotation

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482069/transactional-annotation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post questions just to link to other questions. If you have a specific question, please feel free to ask, and if your question has already been asked, we ask that you gain enough reputation to place a bounty on the existing question.

Comment: It's explained in the official Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative. Note that your question is about Spring, and not Hibernate, since Transactional is a Spring annotation, and HibernateTransactionManager is a Spring class.